# How can I obtain the lawrence of arabia smle?

Tags: battlefield-1

I have seen various scouts use this rifle, but it doesn't show up in my loadout screen. How can it be unlocked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought at first it might be the SMLE variant for completing the final War Story, but that's not the case. Then I thought it might be a super rare Supply Crate unlock. Not that either. Queue the Google search!

[Information revealed here.](https://forums.battlefield.com/en-us/discussion/58127/how-to-get-the-lawrence-of-arabia-smle)

According to this thread from Battlefield's forum, the Lawrence of Arabia SMLE is a Deluxe Edition addition. You can get it by upgrading your game to the Deluxe Edition, but that will set you back around $20.

Buying the Premium Pass for the game only gets you access to all DLC for the game, not the special bonuses for higher tiers of the game (Deluxe or Ultimate).

Comment: if you mean premium version, I did that and it still doesn't show up...

Comment: The Lawrence of Arabia items are part of the Deluxe version of the game. There is no Premium version.

Comment: Premium is buying the season pass

Comment: Find my revised answer above.